# Do we have any annotations to validate the response attribute/fields are not null while sending the response in springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

Below is the 'Student' response class with getter and setter, I am setting the values with the help of setter,
with the help of null checks in codes, it can be done but do we have any annotations for that?

```
 Class Student
    {
     String name;
     String rollno;
     String collegeName;
    
     //Getter and setter
   }
```

Comment: Do you use that class in database as table ?

Comment: @YusufŞengün  No, I am just sending this as a response and before sending the response I need to check.

Comment: You're "sending this as a response" in what context? Response to what?

Comment: Currently there is no out-of-the-box solution for responses, only for request/input validation. You could try annotating the controller (assuming that it is concerning web stuff) with `@Validated` and add the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` but that might also influence the input validation. Then annotate the method/return value with `@Valid` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to perform validation:
Implement your own utility class for validation of objects and validate objects prior passing to some method or use `@Valid` annotation on your objects you are going pass to the method:

```
public void saveStudent(@Valid Student student);
```

In your `Student` class required String fields must be annotated with `@NotBlank` or `NotNull` for other types.

Don't forget to add required dependencies for validation such as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do with your response class:

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ResponseClass implements Serializable {

}
```

This is will not include null and unknown fields in your response json.

Comment: I don't need to ignore the values but I need to generate an error or validation check, if a value is set to null.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use `@NonNull` annotation from Lombok ([link](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull))

Assume your class is:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @NonNull private String name;
    @NonNull private String rollno;
    @NonNull private String collegeName;
}
```

And here is the test:

```
@Test
void CreateStudent() {
    Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> new Student("John", "42", null));
}
```

**update**

In your case (no custom constructors, only default), yo should add `@NonNull` annotation to your setter:

```
public void setName(@NonNull String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

And here is the test:

```
@Test
void CreateStudent() {
    Student student = new Student();
    Assertions.assertThrows(NullPointerException.class, () -> student.setName(null));
}
```

Comment: And that test is going to run successfully?

Comment: @Andrey I am running this on the development system it's not working.

Comment: @Deepak Kumar, what error? I have tested it locally

Comment: please recheck import for annotation as there are alot of similair classes available: `import lombok.NonNull;`

Comment: @Andrey No error, but the response attribute contains the null value for the filed. I am already using Lombok, so no chance of wrong imports but still I have verified that.

Comment: Do I need to use @Data annotation because I have my own getters and setters?

Comment: what constructors do you have for `Student` class?

Comment: @Andrey No constructors only getter and setters this is the response class which will be returned after feeding the data, you can think of this class as a DTO.

Comment: Through null checks yes it can be done just before the value set but I am looking for annotation at class or attribute level which will trigger an error that particular field is missing.

Comment: This is achieved when we receive a request by annotation NotEmpty or NotNull. But how this can be done during sending the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229550/discussion-between-andrey-and-deepak-kumar).

Comment: two more options: implement your own utility class for validation, or add annotation @Valid and implement custom Hibernate validator for your class.

Comment: @DeepakKumar Don't let yourself get confused by this answer. Annotations have no effect in vanilla Java, they only serve as markers to be evaluated by the runtime environment. If you run the test in such a container (something like SpringBootTest should work, I haven't done this myself though), the validation may be performed; if you just run a simple JUnit test in a basic Java setup, the test will fail.

Comment: @daniu if it works in Spring Boot what the issue? I have run both tests locally on new maven project with only Lombok and jUnit5 dependencies and both of them passed. Don't know why you can't reproduce it.

Comment: @Andrey If it works in Spring Boot, you need to _mention this in your answer_, or it is just plain wrong and misleading, as evidenced by the long discussion following it. As it stands, your code just doesn't work as you say it does.

Comment: @daniu, one more time - this works in simple maven project (see above). Please provide proofs that it doesn't work

Comment: I did try it out and must say I stand corrected; Lombok actually does add validation code now. I was not aware of that, sorry.